# Watchdog timer circuit without continual re-trigger

Tags: timer, watchdog

The STWD100 is a watchdog timer, if a pulse from a microprocessor isn't received in X amount of time, it pulls it's output low. This is useful to detect if a processor has experienced an upset (independent of the processor itself). This is the timing diagram of what I want the STWD100 to do:

[image]
Source: https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/06/6a/b3/83/9a/c7/4f/22/CD00176077.pdf/files/CD00176077.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00176077.pdf

I want it to pull the output low if WDI changes and I would like it to stay low
There is no way I have found to do this with the STWD100PY chip. Apparently normal triggering is not really an option and timeout without retrigger is the only option.

[image]
Source: https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/06/6a/b3/83/9a/c7/4f/22/CD00176077.pdf/files/CD00176077.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00176077.pdf

I've checked a few other circuits and cannot find a good simple way to implement this functionality. Anybody know a good way to have a timer watchdog circuit in a small footprint that goes low and stays low?

Comment: SO you want to latch a Timeout rather than perform a reset?  That's easy with a retriggerable timer and latch

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6qV0c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Not sure if this satisfied your design spec and timing diagram